# AngularJS + UI-Router: See if href or ui-sref matches a state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So currently, I am using UI-Router to manage a set of tab directives. By tabs, I mean this UI paradigm:  http://www.hollance.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Screenshot.png

Each tab is able to have a `title`, an `icon`, and a `href` or `ui-sref` associated with it.

Example:

```
<my-tabs>
  <my-tab title="Tab 1" href="#/tab1">
    Content when tab 1 is active!
  </my-tab>
  <my-tab title="Tab 2" ui-sref="tabs.numberTwo()">
    Content when tab 2 is active!
  </my-tab>
</my-tabs>
```

Anyway, the main issue is that when the state is changed programatically or through a browser refresh, I want to be able to know *which* tab to select, based on either the `ui-sref` or `href` attribute.  `$state.(is|includes|contains)` don't seem to do what I need: I can't give `$state.is` a `href` and ask if it matches the current state - neither can I give it a ui-sref.

It's possible I could add a `stateName` attribute or the like to the tab as well, but I would rather not do that if I don't have to.

Basically, I would love to be able to do this in the tab directive:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
   if ($state.matchesHref(attrs.href) || $state.matchesSref(attrs.uiSref)) {
    selectThisTab();
  }
});
```

Any ideas at all to do this would be welcome!

Comment: can you get what you need from window.location?

Comment: @drex Sort of - there is another layer to the problem though.  What if the user is in a child state?  Eg the tab opens a ui-view for the 'list' state, but the navigation is to the 'list.details' state?  I guess I could check the location, know it 'contains' the list state, then activate it and the ui-view inside would render the child state ... I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: @drex do you know if there's a way to get a state with params out of a ui-sref attribute? Then I could do the same for ui-sref. Does ui-router expose the way they do it internally in a service or the like?  I would dig into the source but don't have time right at this moment.

Comment: ui-sref doesn't actually support dynamic values.  The fact that it "works" is unintended side effect.  

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/395
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/745
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/644

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally got it to work, thanks all.

I check against $location.href() for attrs.href, and split the sref to get its stateName for attrs.uiSref.

The split isn't desirable, but it's the best I could find right now.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', selectTabIfMatchesState);
function selectTabIfMatchesState() {
  //get rid of leading # if it exists, to match against $location.path()
  var href = $attr.href && $attr.href.replace(/^#/, '');

  //uiSref is laid out as 'stateName({params})', get only 'stateName'
  var stateName = $attr.uiSref && $attr.uiSref.split('(')[0];

  var includesState = stateName && $state.includes(stateName);
  var includesHref = href && $location.path().indexOf(href) === 0;

  if (includesHref || includesState) {
    // this tab matches current state, go to it!
    tabsCtrl.select($scope);
  }
}
```

Comment: ugh... would be nice to see a working example on a fiddle/plunker.

Comment: could u plz add a example

Answer (score 4):

Checkout next methods:

[http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.%24state)

- `is()`
- `contains()`
- `includes()`

Comment: The problem with those is I don't have an actual state name to match against; I have either a ui-sref (which is a function), or a href - neither of which I can use those methods to match.
`$state.is('/some/url')`, `$state.is('someState({ param: value })')`, etc won't work

Comment: use $state.is correct: `$state.is('admin.website',{siteId: 1})`